# Border to last child not working. Why?

Tags: html, css

Cant understand what the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/ure6o695/1/

```
#wrapper > div {
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid;
border-color: #ff0303;
font-family: Aller_Rg;
padding:21px;
```

}

```
#wrapper > div:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid;
border-color: #ff0303;
```

}

```
#wrapper > img {
float: right;
```

}

```
div {
background: green;
```

}

Comment: Because div isn't last child of wrapper - remove images and you will see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your last `div` is not also the `:last-child` of its parent, since you have two more `img` elements: it is instead the `:last-of-type`

```
#wrapper > div:last-of-type {
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-color: #ff0303;
}
```

Fork: https://jsfiddle.net/vmb9zLrv/

---

If you need to support older browsers (where `:last-of-type` pseudoclass is not available, like `IE7` or `IE8`) you could reverse the logic and apply a `border-right` to all your div and a `border-left` only for `div:first-child`.

Legacy approach: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lty07zq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change this CSS line:

```
#wrapper > div:last-child {
```

To this:

```
#wrapper > div:last-of-type {
```